# Cutting out part of an outlined shape in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

Without rasterising a vector shape, is there a better way to cut out part of an outlined shape in Photoshop? I currently do this:

1. Create shape
2. Double click on layer to edit layer style
3. Select the stroke tab
4. Apply outline to shape
5. Right-click on layer and rasterise
6. Use the eraser tool to cut out part of the shape

When selecting the "Subtract front shape" option, the outline shifts to the outline of the shape I'm cutting out of the original shape.

Comment: If you do care about it being fully vector, then your only sensible option is to create the outline by drawing a box inside a box. But it sounds like you're just hoping to make the workflow simpler, in which case layer mask is probably the simplest.

Comment: Photoshop has extremely limited vector capabilities. You might be better to think about using vector software instead, such as Illustrator, or even Inkscape which is free.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use masking to avoid the cutting of the vector art and preserve it.

try doing masking and then removing the unwanted part of the shape

take the support of these links

https://phlearn.com/tutorial/use-vector-masks-photoshop/
https://helpx.adobe.com/in/photoshop/using/masking-layers-vector-masks.html

To avoid fady pixels around the shape you can always increase the size of the image

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

There's a duplicate question of this somewhere here. Darn if I can find it though so....

---

Create a separate layer for your stroke and add a mask to that layer.

- Duplicate the original artwork layer.
- Set the **Fill** opacity to **0%** on the **Layers Panel**
- Remove all the Layer styles from it *except* the stroke.
- In the **Blending Options** for the **Layer Styles** ensure `Layer Mask Hides Effects` **is** checked
  [image]
- Add a **Layer Mask** to this stroke-only layer
- Paint on the layer mask to hide portions of the stroke.

[image]

You can then **Group** these two layers to keep them together, or combine them into a **Smart Object**.

---

This method works for most Layer styles if you want to hide portions. It will also work in reverse - if you wanted the stroke solid and part of the base image hidden:

[image]

---

If the stroke is applied via the stroke option for vector layers, this still works. **However**, in that case set the **Vector Fill** to **none** and leave the **Fill Opacity** for the stroke layer at **100%**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If in that case, you can use the polygonal lasso tool to cut the perfect edges.

[image: Video]